# Pop up video player displays at odd positions in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have a pop up video player that is being called by an "onClick" in HTML elements. However, when I have more than one video player in a page, in Firefox the first video loads way at the bottom of the page and a viewer has to scroll to see it.

Only in Firefox does it do this.

I've tried absolute, fixed, and other things to make a static positioning on the DIV that makes the video player, but to no avail in Firefox. I even placed the DIV code in various places in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add more information, maybe a codeline or something like that. Is really hard to know what is your problem without really seeing it. Maybe you should try in CSS putting the "-moz-" in the CSS  position.

Answer (score 0):

You have this whole bunch of classes.

```
ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-        resizable videoPlayer
```

and even more classes.

```
ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content
```

Maybe you should check on CSS to all those classes maybe you can find a missing -moz- somewhere. Sometimes CSS templates that are find online have only code for one Web-browser and no compatability for another browser.

Now, apart from my CSS missing line assumption your code looks good.

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't have access to this CSS :-\
Perhaps I can write it inline though.